# is there a native message dialog in Windows Phone much like iPhone does?

Tags: windows-phone-7, native, dialog

I'm working on a Windwos Phone 7 project, where I would like to have a native messagebox, like the simple MessageBox.Show( ) function, only where I can add a few buttons, like "yes" and "no". Everything I found thus far uses an open-source solution, such as [custom Message Box](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2010/10/19/windows-phone-7-custom-message-box.aspx). Is there nothing native to WP7 like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly not.  The standard MessageBox only allows for a very limited set of pre-defined button combinations.  If you want to roll your own, the `Popup` control can be configured to look like the inbuilt MessageBox control, but with the option to display whatever you like inside it.

(Quick and dirty example)

```
<Popup Name="RateAnswerPopup" IsOpen="false" Margin="0" >
    <StackPanel Margin="0" Background="#bb000000" Width="480" Height="800">
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}" Width="456" >
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle3Style}">Is this useful?</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}">Please take a moment to let me know if this was any use to you.</TextBlock>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="12,12,12,0">
                <Button Content="yes" Name="PopupYes" />
                <Button Content="no" Name="PopupNo" />
                <Button Content="maybe" Name="PopupMaybe" />
            </StackPanel>
            <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="DontAskAgainCheck" >Don't ask me again</CheckBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Popup>
```

You may want to add some haptic feedback when you set `RateAnswerPopup.IsOpen=true;` as a cue that the box has appeared, but that's up to you.

Comment: Thanks, it is at least something to lok at =3 
when you say MessageBox only supports a limited set of pre-defined button combinations, you mean the default one, which consists basically of a textfield and a confermation button, or is there a small amount of sets available? ( I really don't need a lot of usability from it, just a yes-no combination ). 
Otherwise, the Popup is definetally worth looking at!

Comment: Check the MessageBoxButton enum in the API for the button options.  (at present on "OK" and "OKCancel" are supported.  You can set a caption and a message in the MessageBox.Show() method, as well as the buttons choice.  In a lot of cases this will be enough but if you need 3 buttons, you have to go custom in some way.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at the [Coding4Fun library](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/). It has the MessagePrompt and InputPromt that do what your after. I end up including the Coding4Fun libary in most of the projects I do.

Comment: I looked at it too, but the problem is, I cannot use any open-source libraries, just native Silverlight

Comment: If you can't use open source but you can use third party controls, Telerik RadControls have a MessageBox that is more configurable.

http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/overview/all-controls.aspx#messagebox

Answer (score 0):

I have had good results using the Coding 4 Fun toolkit that is available from codeplex - http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/ - to display MessageBoxes and the like.